# What are some example use cases for Newton's Method being extended to higher dimensions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, applications

I'm currently working on a project to attempt to optimize a program that runs Newton's Method in higher dimensions - the actual computer science isn't important. However, what is a lot more important is that I want to test it in real-world scenarios, and am having difficulty finding cases where it has been used (or could be used) to solve significant real-world problems. Therefore, I'm wondering if any of you know or have encountered such problems in the real world.

P.S. If this is the wrong place to post it, kindly redirect me to wherever is more appropriate.

Comment: I think that this is the right forum for your question. I’d rather like to see an example of Newton-Raphson worked out in this case, too.

Comment: [GPS triangulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445808/147873)

Comment: interior point methods, although dealing with nonnegativity is a bit more cumbersome than standard Newton's method

Comment: @RobinAldabanx: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19690005172.pdf, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264236804_SOLUTION_OF_THE_CHARACTERISTIC_EQUATION_IN_THE_DYNAMIC_ANALYSIS_OF_A_PLANE_FRAME_USING_THE_NEWTON-RAPHSON_METHOD